# How to go about programmatically solving equation like <=0 implies >0

Tags: logic, predicate

Say there is this expression,

r>0

The value of r is <=0, So if we substitute in the above equation, the equation becomes

<=0 > 0

So my question is I want to say does <=0 implies >0? So for this input it is false. But there are inputs where we can't come to the conclusion, Say for this example

<5 > 0

So for this does <5 implies >0 ? for some values yes and for some values no. So for this example it is undefined.

I want to write a program that takes 2 arguments(like the example given above) and my program should able to print true or false or undefined. How to approach this problem, I read about first order logic, predicates but I can't come to a conclusion.

The input is like two objects, func(Object value1, Object value 2). As per above example value 1 is <=0 and value 2 is >0. So this function should compute does <=0 implies >0 and print the output as true or false or undefined.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Are the inputs things like "r > 0" and "r <= 5", or just 0 and 5?

Comment: I have updated in the original post. Thanks for asking.

Comment: So value1 is a string literal "<=0" and value2 is a string ">0"?

Comment: Yes @LionelFoxcroft

Comment: That question is unanswerable in its current form, because there isn't enough information to understand the scope of what you're doing. If you know the inputs will always be in the form "<=x" and ">y" for two numbers x and y, then that would make it solvable. If there are no such limitations, then this turns into a very difficult problem that is too expansive to be appropriate for SO.

Comment: Yes exactly, the input can be of varying form. So yea even I thought is difficult to address.